# How do I pull a multiple pieces of data from a while loop and put into a table

Tags: list-manipulation, simulation, astronomy

I am wanting to pull multiple pieces of data from a while loop and put it in a list. The example I have added below is a table with inputted data that I found. Im pretty sure the syntax is unrelated to Mathematica, but it gives you an idea of how I want to display it once I run all of my simulations. For mine I want it to display the following along the top similar to the example.

- Planet
- Mass
- Perihelion (Distance/ Velocity)
- Aphelion (Distance/Velocity)
- Semimajor Axis
- Sidereal Orbit period
- Orbit eccentricity
- Mean orbital velocity

From my simulation, I am obtaining the distance and velocity of the aphelion and the sidereal period from the `While` loop and I want to extract that data so that I can insert it into a table.

I didn't know how to give just example to where it made sense, but I have uploaded my mathematica sheet as a pdf [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EVHgoDhq2fuLbF6TuPAEVu_TNk3RNDoI) and the notebook [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nwicpuYBhqWPKz2NkdquMTwvKkfxMzGD).

[image]

EDIT

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mSun = 1.98855*10^30; (* Mass of Sun, kg *) 
G = 6.67384*10^-11;     (*Universal Gravitational Constant,N m^2 kg^-2*)
(* Create list of planet names *)
planets = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
(* Create list of planet masses *)
mass = {0.3301, 4.8676, 5.9726, 0.64174, 1898.3, 568.36, 86.816, 102.42};
mass = 10^24*mass;

Print["EARTH"];     (* EARTH *)

vini = {0., 30.29*10^3};     (* Initial Velocity of Earth{x, y} , m/s *)
Print["vini= " , vini];
rini = {147.09*10^9, 0.};     (*  Initial Position of Earth {x, y}, m *)
Print["rini= " , rini];     (* copy rini \[Rule] rc, vini \[Rule] vc, where 'c' means "current" *)

rc = rini; vc = vini;
(* time in s *)
\[CapitalDelta]t = 60.;
t = 0;
f = 0;
i = 0;
KeepGoing = True;
nsp = 10000;

While[KeepGoing,
 {
  t = t + \[CapitalDelta]t;
  i = i + 1;
  fold = f;
  If[Mod[i, nsp] == 0, 
   Print["\nstep = ", i, ", time = ", t, " s = ", t/60., " min = ", t/
    3600., " h = ", t/86400., " days"]];
  (* update rn, where 'n' means "new" *)
  rn = rc + vc*\[CapitalDelta]t;
  If[Mod[i, nsp] == 0, Print["\trn = ", rn, ", |rn| = ", Norm[rn]]];
  (* update v *)
  vn = vc - (G*mSun)/Norm[rc]^3*rc*\[CapitalDelta]t;
  (* print *)
  If[Mod[i, nsp] == 0, Print["\tvn = ", vn, " |vMn| = ", Norm[vn]]];
  (* copy vn \[Rule] vc and rn \[Rule] rc *)
  rc = rn; vc = vn;
  (* calculate true anomaly *)
  polar = ToPolarCoordinates[rc];
  f = polar[[2]]/Degree;
  If[Mod[i, nsp] == 0, Print["\tf (true anomaly) = ", f, "\[Degree]"]];
  If[fold < 0 && f >= 0, {KeepGoing = False; 
    Print["\nNOW WILL STOP - f changed from - to +"]}];
  If[Abs[Abs[f] - 180.] <= 0.005 || ! KeepGoing,
   {
    Print[
     "\n\tTrue anomaly is close to 180\[Degree] or completed full \
orbit, f = ", f, "\[Degree]"];
    Print["\tstep = ", i, ", time = ", t, " s = ", t/60., " min = ", 
     t/3600., " h = ", t/86400., " days"];
    Print["\trn = ", rn, ", |rMn| = ", Norm[rn]*10^-3*10^-6, 
     "\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\) km"];
    Print["\tvn = ", vn, " |vMn| = ", Norm[vn]*10^-3, " km/s"]
    }];


  }
 ]
```

Comment: Take a look at `Sow/Reap`. Thanks for providing a background but could you create a toy example to mimic your procedure and the result you would like to get?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have not migrated to Mathematica's programming paradigm. Your "C" programming style is not the best way to do things in *Mathematica*, you should read [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397) to help you change paradigm.

Some examples of things that could have been done differently in your code:

### NDSolve

The integration of the equations of motion you doesn't need to be done by hand, you could use [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html). If you need to stop the integration at specic events you can use ["EventLocator" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html)

### Constructing Lists

At any point of your iteration you could [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) a list or use [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html). You could also use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) for your iterations.

Using [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) into a notebook make little sense in Mathematica.

### PlanetData

You can take advantage of Mathematica curated data

Planet names:

```
PlanetData[All, "Name"]
(* {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"} *)
```

Planet mass:

```
QuantityMagnitude@
 UnitConvert[PlanetData[PlanetData[], "Mass"], "Kilograms"]
(* {3.30104*10^23, 4.86732*10^24, 5.9721986*10^24, 6.41693*10^23,
  1.89813*10^27, 5.68319*10^26, 8.68103*10^25, 1.02410*10^26} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For an iterated function system like this, `Nest` and relatives (in particular `NestListWhile` here) are a fine toolkit. First, write your time step as a function of the state variables, yielding a new list of state variables. Here's a simple example, constant 1D acceleration. Here, `t` is time, `h` is height, `v` is velocity.

```
timeStep[{t_, h_, v_}] := {t + deltat, h + deltat (v + a deltat/2 ), v + a deltat}
```

To decide when to end, we need a test function.

```
test[{t_, h_, v_}] := h < hlimit
```

For injecting constant parameters, `Block` is useful for avoiding global definitions. `TableForm` is good for formatting output.

```
Block[{a = 30., deltat = 1., hlimit = 100000.},
  NestWhileList[timeStep, {0., 0., 0.}, test]] // TableForm
```

Yielding:

```
0.  0.      0.
1.  15.     30.
2.  60.     60.
3.  135.    90.
...
81. 98415.  2430.
82. 100860. 2460.
```